# CSS not appearing or functioning as expected

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using django for templates. Here is the base:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<main role="main" class="container">
  <div class="pb-2 mb-2">
    {% block page_header %}{% endblock page_header %}
  </div>
  <div class="mt-1 border-top">
    {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
  </div>
</main>
```

When the page_header div is given the class border-bottom, the border appears at the bottom of the contents instead of the page_header, not separating the two divs at all. When the content div is given the class attribute border-top, the contents are clearly separated from the page_header by a line. Why doesn't this occur with border-bottom?

page_header, plugged into the {% block page_header %}

```
<h2 class="d-inline">Topic: Private</h2>
<p class="ml-3 d-inline">Entries:</p>
<p class="alert-gray rounded p-1 pl-2 pr-2 d-inline border-0">2/3</p>

<a class="btn btn-gray p-2 ml-5 d-inline" href="/edit_topic/13/">
    <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
    Edit topic name
</a>

<form class="ml-5 d-inline" action="/delete_topic/13/" method='post' title="Delete Topic">
    <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="">
    <button class="btn btn-red p-2" name="submit">
        <i class="fas fa-minus-circle"></i>
        Delete topic
    </button>
</form>

<div class="btn-group dropright ml-5 d-inline" title="Visibility">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md rounded-sm" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
     
            <i class="far fa-eye-slash"></i>
        
    </button>


     <div class="dropdown-menu w-10">
        <form class="dropdown-item" action="/topic_visibility/13/0" method='post' title="Private">
            <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="">

            <button class="dropdown-button" name="submit">
                <i class="far fa-eye-slash"></i>
            </button>
        </form>

        <form class="dropdown-item" action="/topic_visibility/13/1" method='post' title="Public">
            <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="">

            <button class="dropdown-button" name="submit">
                <i class="far fa-eye"></i>
            </button>
        </form>

</div>
```

Comment: post the page_header div code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to an un-closed div tag.